# Sudoku solution checker

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, sudoku

I have a program in Java that check if a sudoku is valid or not, I have two methods, the first is check the sum of all columns, sub-grids, rows and tell if is 45, and the second is check if the sum of all the sudoku is 405 or not if yes, so the sudoku is valid so I'm looking for a counter example, that in input I have a valid sudoku but the programme tell that is not valid , so this is the code :

```
public class test_checker {
    static final boolean valide=true;
    static final boolean non_valide=false;

    // verify every sub-grid if it is valid
        static boolean check_subgrid(int a[][],int ei,int ej){
            int sum=0;
            for(int i=ei;i<ei+3;i++){           
                for(int j=ej;j<ej+3;j++){
                    sum=sum+a[j][i];
                }
            }
            if(sum!=45) return non_valide;
            else return valide;
        }
        //verify a sudoku by sum of every row & column & sub-grid
        static boolean Checker1(int a[][]){
            int sum=0;
            //check row
            for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
                sum=0;
                for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                    sum=sum+a[i][j];
                }
                if(sum!=45) return non_valide;

            }
            //check column
            for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
                sum=0;
                for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                    sum=sum+a[j][i];
                }
                if(sum!=45) return non_valide;
            }       
            //check sub-grid
            for(int i=0;i<9;i=i+3){
                for(int j=0;j<3;j=j+3){
                    if(check_subgrid(a,i,j)==non_valide) return non_valide;
                }
            }
            return valide;
        }
        //verify by sum of all sudoku  
        static boolean Checker2(int a[][]){
            int sum=0;
            for(int i=0;i<9;i++){           
                for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                    sum=sum+a[i][j];
                }
            }   
            if(sum!=405) return non_valide;
            else return valide;
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] sudoku =
            {
                {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
                {4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3},
                {7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6},
                {3,1,2,9,7,8,6,4,5},
                {6,4,5,3,1,2,9,7,8},
                {9,7,8,6,4,5,3,1,2},
                {2,3,1,5,6,4,8,9,7},
                {5,6,4,8,9,7,2,3,1},
                {8,9,7,2,3,1,5,6,4}
            };
        if(Checker1(sudoku)) System.out.println("it's valide (checker1)!");
        else System.out.println("it's not valide !");
        if(Checker2(sudoku)) System.out.println("it's valide (checker2) !");
        else System.out.println("it's not valide !");

    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't check the sum of the numbers, because it can have false positives (repeated numbers that also sums 45). You should check if the numbers don't repeat.

Comment: Is this question more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Of course there is no valid 9x9 Sudoku that fails to satisfy your criteria.  It follows directly from the definition of a valid Sudoku. The question you *should* be asking is whether there is an ***invalid*** 9 by 9 grid that nevertheless ***does*** satisfy your criteria.

Comment: @Hugo are you sure! give me a counter exemple of sudoku solution that's correct and my prgramm tell that's not valide

Comment: And absolutely there are grids whose elements sum to 405, but that are not valid Sudoku.  Whether the first method is also broken is a harder question.

Comment: @Paul why ? i don't know how use that website and for what !

Comment: @JohnBollinger for the 405 i know for sure that's a false method just i added it to be sure , now i'm looking to check the other one

Comment: @Paul I don't think so - they aren't asking for a code review, they're asking for a counter-example to their approach for handling sudoku validity.

Comment: How about instead choosing a variation on your technique whose correctness is more easily provable?  For example, instead of adding up the grid elements, combine corresponding bitmasks (`sum = sum | (1 << (a[i][j] - 1))`).

Comment: @Adelov, actually I found an example of an invalid grid that your programs returns as a valid sudoku solution.
       `sudoku = new int[][] {
             {15, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0},
             { 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, 0 },
             { 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15 }, 
             {15, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0 },
             { 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, 0 },
             { 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15 }, 
             {15, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0 },
             { 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, 0 },
             { 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15 } };`

Comment: But, of course, if you're assuming that all grids will be sudoku valid solutions, then ignore my comment :)

Comment: @Hugo , nah i'm talking about value in [1,9] , we can not use 15

Comment: You told that "I have a program in Java that check if a sudoku is valid or not". If this program accepts a grid with zeroes and 15, it's not checking correctly. Anyway, in the answers below there are another counter examples with values between 1 and 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @John Bollinger said

> you should be asking is whether there is an invalid 9 by 9 grid that
>   nevertheless does satisfy your criteria.

The simplest 2 cases, which comes to my mind are:

```
{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5}
```

and your example, where you would put 0's instead of 1's
and 10's instead of 9's. Make sure each fields are distinct in rows, columns and sub-grids and are in interval of [1,9].

Answer (score 1):

For checker2 you can just invert two values of two rows. Here I inverted 4 and 1 of the first and second rows, obviously it's an invalid sudoku, but checker2 will give you a positive result

```
            {4,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
            {1,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3},
            {7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6},
            {3,1,2,9,7,8,6,4,5},
            {6,4,5,3,1,2,9,7,8},
            {9,7,8,6,4,5,3,1,2},
            {2,3,1,5,6,4,8,9,7},
            {5,6,4,8,9,7,2,3,1},
            {8,9,7,2,3,1,5,6,4}
```